# Find all circle objects

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to find all circle objects on image using python wrapper for opencv.
Something like [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/23/detecting-circles-in-an-image/).

Using [cv2.HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) but I can't find optimal parameters.
Is it possible at all?

My code:

```
import cv, cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread("C:/1.jpg")

grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
blur= grey
#blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, (0,0), 10)
circles =  cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 5, np.array([]), 40, 80, 5, 50)#params?
if circles is not None:
        for c in circles[0]:
                cv2.circle(im, (c[0],c[1]), c[2], (0,255,0),2)
edges = cv2.Canny( blur, 40, 80 )

cv2.imwrite("C:/circle.jpg",im)
cv2.imwrite("C:/canny.jpg",edges)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `circles =  cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 16, np.array([]), 15, 36, 9, 35)`, matlab result for `CircularHough_Grd(red, [3 35],20, 15, 1);` is here(http://i.stack.imgur.com/bw5HL.jpg). it still seems to catch more bubbles. matlab version uses `adapthisteq` whose equivalent in opencv is `createCLAHE`. i have tried it but result is not much different which means it's probably the difference between circularhough implementations. i have noticed that smaller radaii range catches more things so maybe try multiple different ranges and combine them together

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task regarding the image you provided.

Try to find a good range for your radius (`minRadius`,`maxRadius`: not to big, otherwise some small circles well be seen as one big circle) too improve your result.

Otherwise i would suggest seperating the Objects with another approach ([watershedding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) for example)